# Foreach in foreach alternative

Tags: php, foreach

I am stuck trying to figure out how I can have a foreach in a foreach without it being quantity $item x quantity $iteminfo.
Have a look.

```
$inventory = file_get_contents("https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/".$_SESSION['steamid']."/inventory/json/730/2");

$myarrayInv = json_decode($inventory, true);  
if(isset($myarrayInv['rgDescriptions']))
{
    if(isset($myarrayInv['rgInventory'])) {
        foreach($myarrayInv['rgDescriptions'] as $item) {
            foreach($myarrayInv['rgInventory'] as $iteminfo) {
            echo "<div class='item'><img class='item' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/".$item['icon_url']."' height='90' width='120'/><span class='caption'>".$item['name']." | ".$iteminfo['id']."</span></div>&nbsp;"; 
        }
    }
}
```

This code is support to display items, when I remove the loop for "$iteminfo" the quantity of items displays right. Like this.

item1, item2, item3, item4.

When I add the forloop back, it gets like this.

item1, item1, item1, item1, item2, item2, item2, item2, item3, item3, item3, item3, item4 item4 item4 item4.

I don't know what a good solution would be, any ideas?

**Edit:**
Maybe I was not clear enough about what I want to achieve, see. The $item array doens't contain the itemid, but $iteminfo does contain itemid.

I want the itemid to be displayed with the itemname and picture, this would work if I had a while-loop in a while-loop.

Comment: Post a sample array.

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Comment: Edited answer..

Comment: I still don't understand. How are the two arrays related?

Comment: If `$myarrayInv['rgDescriptions'][index]` corresponds to the same item in`$myarrayInv['rgInventory'][index]` then you can use a for loop and access both arrays by their index

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Can you post the result of `echo '<pre style="border:1px solid; text-align:left; background:grey; font-size:16px; padding:5px;color:black; display:none;">'
, print_r($myarrayInv , true), '<hr/></pre> ';`

Comment: How would that be helpful?

Comment: I'd actually suggest looping on just rgInventory, using its classid and instanceid to reference the right rgDescriptions object. As each desc obj is named by "{$classid}_{$instanceid}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each rgDescription is keyed by [classid_instanceid] from the rgInventory, not a straight like-index. So this may work out better for you (I ran a test using my personal steam inventory, seems to show icons and names):

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'. $_SESSION['steamid'] .'/inventory/json/730/2');

$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data['rgInventory'] as $inv) {
    $desc = $data['rgDescriptions'][ $inv['classid'] .'_'. $inv['instanceid'] ];

    echo "<div class='item'><img class='item' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/". $desc['icon_url'] ."' height='90' width='120'/><span class='caption'>". $desc['name'] ." | ". $inv['id'] ."</span></div>&nbsp;";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use one loop, and then use the same index in both arrays.

```
foreach ($myarrayInv['rgDescriptions'] as $index => $item) {
    $iteminfo = $myarrayInv['rgInventory'][$index];
    echo "<div class='item'><img class='item' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/".$item['icon_url']."' height='90' width='120'/><span class='caption'>".$item['name']." | ".$iteminfo['id']."</span></div>&nbsp;";
}
```

You could also consider reorganizing your data. Instead of two arrays, use a single array with `rgDescriptions` and `rgInventory` keys.

Comment: I got this error **Undefined index: $index in** on the line `$iteminfo = $myarrayInv['rgInventory'][$index];`

Comment: Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: Are you using the exact code as written above? The error suggests otherwise.

Comment: I am not, but I've tried copying the exact code and the error remains.

Comment: I upvoted this because it is sound logic for many uses. (but with steam's silly json logic, the index references is weird)

Comment: @Emrik `$index` is set in the `foreach()` line: `$index => $item` Did you copy that correctly?